# BluetoothGattCallback Not called onConnectionStateChange, When bluetooth hardware explicitly disabled by user

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

`onconnection` stage changed in `bluetoothGattCallback` is not called for nougat and above devices when bluetooth hardware is switchedOff by user. In below  Nougat its getting called. Is anything changed in Android Nougat? What is correct way to implement BLE.

Comment: show some code please